# Replace multiple occurances of a string between html tags

Tags: replace

Given a html file that contains

```
<a>black_dogs</a>  <a>black_dogs_bite</a>  <a>black_dogs_bite_children</a>
```

This code will only replace the first occurrence of the "_" string

```
var allA = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i=0,n=allA.length;i<n;i++) {
    allA[i].innerHTML=allA[i].innerHTML.replace("_"," ");
}
```

How can I change this to find all of the occurances of "_" between the tags?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: You have to use a simple regex instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression with the `g` global flag:

```
.replace(/_/g, " ")
```